# why can't equate pointer to nullptr

Tags: while-loop, null, nullptr

In the follwing program I was searching of lowest comman ancesstor in a BST.

The main problem here is that !root doesn't works like root!=nullptr.
Here line 1 works perfect. But line 2 gives wrong answer.
Please tell why line 2 desn't works but line 1 does.

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * struct TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode *left;
 *     TreeNode *right;
 *     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
 * };
 */

class Solution {
public:
    TreeNode* lowestCommonAncestor(TreeNode* root, TreeNode* p, TreeNode* q) {
        int small=min(p->val, q->val);
        int big=max(p->val, q->val);
        while(root!=nullptr){   // line 1
        // while(!root){        // line 2
            int x=(root->val);
            if(x>big){
                root=root->left;
            }
            else if(x<small){
                root=root->right;
            }
            else{
                return root;
            }
        }
        return nullptr;
    }
};
```

Comment: Just as an aside, and I know it's in the comment area rather than the code, but you really should be using `nullptr` in preference to `NULL` in C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

Short of defining `nullptr` to be something weird (like 7), there should be no difference between `x != nullptr` and `! x`, for any given pointer `x`.

It may be worthwhile printing out `nullptr` and `root` just inside the loop as well as the comparison results (and pointers, just in case your tree is corrupt), to see if something weird is happening, something like:

```cpp
while (!root) {
    std::cout
        << static_cast<void*>(root) << ' '
        << static_cast<void*>(root->left) << ' '
        << static_cast<void*>(root->right) << ' '
        << static_cast<void*>(nullptr) << ' '
        << (! root) << ' '
        << (root != nullptr) << std::endl;
    int x=(root->val);
    // ... and so on
```

The output of that may go a great deal toward showing what's wrong with your situation<sup>(a)</sup>.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> One of my favourite mantras is "when in doubt, print it out", right up there with:

- Get it working first, *then* get it working fast.
- You can't get any less optimised than "wrong".

:-)